# How to select element after DOM reload in webdriverio in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, webdriver, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I've been tasked to perform the followings using Mocha and webdriverio:

1. `[done]` Open https://cloud.google.com/
2. `[done]` By clicking the search button on the portal at the top of the page, enter in the search field "Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator"
3. `[done]` Start the search by clicking the search button.
4. `[done]` In the search results, click "Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator" and go to the calculator page.
5. `[done]` Activate the COMPUTE ENGINE section at the top of the page `//selected by default`
6. `[In Progress]` Fill in the form with the following data:

   - Number of instances: 4 `//element id #input_77`
   - Instance type: n1-standard-8 (vCPUs: 8, RAM: 30 GB)
   - Select Add GPUs

     - Number of GPUs: 1
     - GPU type: NVIDIA Tesla V100
   - Local SSD: 2x375 Gb
   - Datacenter location: Frankfurt (europe-west3)
   - Commited usage: 1 Year

I've tried to select the element (`number of instances`) both by id:

```
const numOfInstances = await $('#input_77')
```

and XPath:

```
const numOfInstances = await $('//*[@id="input_77"]')
```

But I've got error message: `element ("#input_77") still not existing after 15000ms`

The whole code block here:

```
 it('Choose the number instances', async () => {
        const numOfInstances = await $('#input_77')
        //await numOfInstances.waitForExist() //tried this method, too. but still the same error
        await numOfInstances.setValue(4)
    })
```

I guess the problem is not with the way of selecting the element, but finding it after DOM refreshed due to search in step 3 and 4.

The whole code is here: https://pastebin.com/79ghTbHC

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Off-topic, do you know if you want to make provision by code, you can use https://www.terraform.io/ ?

Comment: I'm not supposed to use libraries/frameworks/technologies other than unit-testing framework and webdriverio.